# How can I change the _DEFAULT_TIMEOUT (120 seconds) in google.auth.transport.requests Python library?

Tags: python, http, gcloud, google-api-python-client, timeoutexception

I use this code which occasionally gets timeouts when trying to connect to the server. Now I'm trying to find a way to decrease the timeout time so that *refresh()* throws an exception must faster than after 120 seconds.

```
def _get_access_token():
  """Retrieve a valid access token that can be used to authorize requests."""

  credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
  scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'])

  request_succeeded = False

  while True: # Try until we get a token from Google.
    try:
      credentials.refresh( google.auth.transport.requests.Request() ) # Change timeout time here?
      access_token = credentials.token 
      request_succeeded = True
    except:
      print("Exception occurred, connecting to Google again...")
    if request_succeeded:
      break

  # Write access token to file:
  f = open("access_token_firebase.txt", "w")
  f.write(access_token)
  f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  start_time = time.time()
  _get_access_token()
  print("Python script finished. Took: %s seconds to complete." % round(time.time() - start_time, 2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/auth/transport/requests.html#AuthorizedSession.request) as reference. As you can see there, you should declare your timeout and use it in the request like below

```
 def __call__(
        self,
        url,
        method="GET",
        body=None,
        headers=None,
        timeout=_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        **kwargs
    ):
        """Make an HTTP request using requests.

        Args:
            url (str): The URI to be requested.
            method (str): The HTTP method to use for the request. Defaults
                to 'GET'.
            body (bytes): The payload / body in HTTP request.
            headers (Mapping[str, str]): Request headers.
            timeout (Optional[int]): The number of seconds to wait for a
                response from the server. If not specified or if None, the
                requests default timeout will be used.
            kwargs: Additional arguments passed through to the underlying
                requests :meth:`~requests.Session.request` method.

        Returns:
            google.auth.transport.Response: The HTTP response.

        Raises:
            google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: If any exception occurred.
        """
        try:
            _LOGGER.debug("Making request: %s %s", method, url)
            response = self.session.request(
                method, url, data=body, headers=headers, timeout=timeout, **kwargs
            )
            return _Response(response)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as caught_exc:
            new_exc = exceptions.TransportError(caught_exc)
            six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've read the documentation but I can't figure out how to use the __call__ function. I've tried something like this:
`
while True: # Try until we get a token from Google.
    try:
      response = google.auth.transport.requests.Request().__call__('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', timeout=10)
      credentials.refresh(response) 
      access_token = credentials.token 
`
but that doesn't work. And from what I can tell, it's not possible to pass a timeout argument when creating an instance of the Request class.

Comment: At this other link https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/auth/transport/requests.py you can find another example on how to use it. And regarding your last question, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up going with is

```
from google.auth.transport import requests as google_requests
class GoogleRequestWithTimeout(google_requests.Request):
    GOOGLE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 5  # seconds

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__call__(*args, timeout=self.GOOGLE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, **kwargs)
```

so you can now do

```
credentials.refresh(GoogleRequestWithTimeout())
```

See discussion here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/pull/171